Is there a way to add a meeting occurring certain time every (let's say) third Wednesday of the month into Google Calendar?
Is there a way to add a meeting occurring certain time every (let's say) third Wednesday of the month into Google Calendar?

What's that got to do with anything?

On https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/week, go to a third Wednesday of the month into Google Calendar, then custom, then monthly on the third Wednesday:

